# Is there a way to concatenate multiple data frame entries into a single entry?

Tags: r, excel, transformation, data-manipulation

I am working with some pre- and post-activity data in an excel spreadsheet where a single question might have several answers (and the student must select all correct answers to get full credit for that question), but the way the data was originally formatted, each individual response is listed in its own row, with other meta-data (database information, student username, gender, etc) is just replicated for each row - I'll detail this with an example below.

```
>data
Database   Username   Gender   InterviewType   Question                    Answer
1          steve      Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 1"
1          steve      Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 2"
1          steve      Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 3"
1          steve      Male     Pre             Please indicate your race.  "White"
1          steve      Male     Pre             Explain how you would...    "Response"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 1"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 2"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             Please indicate your race.  "White"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             Explain how you would...    "Response"
1          jack       Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 1"
1          jack       Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 2"
1          jack       Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 3"
1          jack       Male     Pre             Please indicate your race.  "Black"
1          jack       Male     Pre             Explain how you would...    "Response"
3          billy      Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 1"
3          billy      Male     Pre             Which of the following...   "Response 2"
3          billy      Male     Pre             Please indicate your race.  "Other"
3          billy      Male     Pre             Explain how you would...    "Response"
```

The data is more usable when I format it such that each individual question has its own column in a data frame, so with a collaborative effort, we wrote the following code to turn each unique question into its own column:

```
x = data
require(stringr)
temp = which(x$Db == "Db")
x = x[-temp,]
questions = unique(x$Question)
concdMeta = apply(x[,c('Db', 'username', 'gender', 'interviewForm')],
                  MARGIN = 1,
                  FUN = paste,
                  collapse = " & ")
students = unique(concdMeta)

out = matrix(nrow = length(students),
         ncol = 4 + length(questions))
row.names(out) = students
colnames(out) = c(colnames(x)[1:4], questions)
out = data.frame(out)

for(i in 1:nrow(out)) {
  Z = str_split(row.names(out)[i], ' & ')[[1]]
  for(j in 1:4) {
    out[i, j] = Z[j]
  }
}


for (i in 1:nrow(x))
{
  db = x$Db[i]
  un = x$username[i]
  g = x$gender[i]
  iF = x$interviewForm[i]
  q = x$Question[i]
  a = x$Answer[i]

  this.meta = paste(x[i, 1:4], collapse = " & ")
  matching.row = row.names(out) == this.meta

  out[matching.row, 4 + which(questions == q)] = a

}

out[is.na(out)] = "NA"
```

The above code works fantastically, except for one issue we have: it lists the final response to the question as whatever the last response was for that student. So for, say, Steve above, it would only list "Response 3", or "Response 2" for Jenna, etc. Like so:

```
>data.reformatted
Database   Username   Gender   InterviewType   Which of the following...  Please indicate...  Explain how...
1          steve      Male     Pre             "Response 3"               "White"             "Response"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             "Response 2"               "White"             "Response"              
1          jack       Male     Pre             "Response 3"               "Black"             "Response"              
3          billy      Male     Pre             "Response 2"               "Other"             "Response"
```

Is there an addition we can make to the code above to make it so that it concatenates all responses into a single cell? Meaning the final dataset would look like this:

```
Database   Username   Gender   InterviewType   Which of the following...             Please indicate...   Explain how...
1          steve      Male     Pre             "Response 1, Response 2, Response 3"  "White"             "Response"
2          jenna      Female   Pre             "Response 1, Response 2"              "White"             "Response"
1          jack       Male     Pre             "Response 1, Response 2, Response 3"  "Black"             "Response"
3          billy      Male     Pre             "Response 1, Response 2"              "Other"             "Response"
```

Comment: please use `dput(data)`. Also, http://www.r-bloggers.com/reshape-and-aggregate-data-with-the-r-package-reshape2/ should help you replace that function :)

Comment: Sorry about the data issue, I had never heard of dput in R for this. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my answer above, a more automated version would be something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


data$rownum <- 1:nrow(data) # add row numbers as a column 
# needed for the spread function to work 
# (complains about duplicates otherwise)

questions <- as.character(unique(data$Question))
qNames <- paste0("q", 1:length(questions))

data <- data.frame(lapply(data, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# change questions names to question keys
for (q in 1:length(questions)){
  data[data$Question == questions[q], "Question"] <- qNames[q]
}

data.wide <- data %>% 
  spread(Question, Answer)

#colnames(data.wide)[6:8] <- c("Explain", "Indicate", "Which") # change column names
data.wide <- data.frame(lapply(data.wide, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data.wide[is.na(data.wide)] <- ""
head(data.wide)



# Group by necessary columns and merge rows using Reduce and paste    
dummy <- data.wide %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Database, Username, Gender, InterviewType) 


# Create command as a string
str_start <- "dummy2 <- dummy %>% dplyr::summarize("
str_end <- paste0(qNames[length(qNames)]," = Reduce(function(...) paste(...),", qNames[length(qNames)],"))")

str_middle <- ""                   
for (q in 1:(length(qNames) - 1 )){
  str_middle <- paste(str_middle, qNames[q] ," = Reduce(function(...) paste(...),", qNames[q], "),")

}                   

str_final <- paste0(str_start, str_middle, str_end)

# Execute Command
eval(parse(text = str_final))

# Change columns names
for (q in 1:length(questions)){
   colnames(dummy2)[colnames(dummy2) == qNames[q]] <- as.character(questions[q])
}
```

Comment: That does it, perfectly! Thank you so much! That way definitely increases the efficiency of the code a lot more than repeating the same line of code 80 times.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together some code that seems to do what you want. 
You will need to install `dplyr` in order to run this.

```
data$rownum <- 1:nrow(data) # add row numbers as a column 
                            # needed for the spread function to work 
                            # (complains about duplicates otherwise)
data.wide <- data %>% 
    spread(Question, Answer)

colnames(data.wide)[6:8] <- c("Explain", "Indicate", "Which") # change column names
data.wide[is.na(data.wide)] <- ""
head(data.wide)
  Database Username Gender InterviewType rownum    Explain Indicate        Which
1        1     jack   Male           Pre     10                     "Response 1"
2        1     jack   Male           Pre     11                     "Response 2"
3        1     jack   Male           Pre     12                     "Response 3"
4        1     jack   Male           Pre     13             "Black"             
5        1     jack   Male           Pre     14 "Response"                      
6        1    steve   Male           Pre      1                     "Response 1


# Group by necessary columns and merge rows using Reduce and paste    
result <- data.wide %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Database, Username, Gender, InterviewType) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    Which = Reduce(function(...) paste(...), Which),
    Indicate = Reduce(function(...) paste(...), Indicate),
    Explain = Reduce(function(...) paste(...), Explain))

head(as.data.frame(result))
  Database Username Gender InterviewType                                    Which    Indicate        Explain
1        1     jack   Male           Pre "Response 1" "Response 2" "Response 3"      "Black"      "Response"
2        1    steve   Male           Pre "Response 1" "Response 2" "Response 3"      "White"      "Response"
3        2    jenna Female           Pre              "Response 1" "Response 2"      "White"      "Response"
4        3    billy   Male           Pre              "Response 1" "Response 2"      "Other"      "Response"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello! I've just run this for the dataset and everything appears to work out as we had initially wanted. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer has worked for you it would be good to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Follow-up: If we had upwards of 80 or more individual, unique questions in the set and wanted to make the dplyr::summarize(...) more efficient, is that possible?

For example, if we saved the list of questions into a variable, q, and had to run the dplyr::summarize bit at the end there.

Instead of doing: dplyr:summarize(q1 = reduce(...., q1), q2 = reduce(..., q2), q3 = reduce(..., q3), etc, etc. At the end, we would just rename the columns from the saved list of questions. Is there a loop we can run to do that more efficiently instead of writing 80-odd individual lines?

Comment: There is a way, I will add another answer as it will be easier to read the code there.